# Show/Reveal Content

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting out with Javascript. I cannot figure out for the life of my why a basic function won't work. I'm trying to make so when you click the button, the "World" disappears.

I'm not really seeing a logical reason as to why this shouldn't work; I'm basically copying from w3schools introductory JS tutorials.

I thought it was an issue with the new "hidden" attributed in html5, but I tried the usual "style="display: none;"" route too and it didn't work.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6qDap/966/

Thanks in advance for helping me with such a simple question!

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="my_button" onclick="hide()">Hello</button>
<div id="my_div">World</div>
```

JS:

```
function hide()
{
document.getElementById('my_div').setAttribute('hidden');
}
```

Comment: In your jsfiddle, in the top left where there's an option for JavaScript to load as 'OnLoad', change it to 'No wrap - in <head>'. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized your code should work correctly. You should try putting the script in the head to make sure it loads before the DOM.

Ignore my previous answer:

I think you're looking for `display: none`

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wsf7H/) to show an example

Comment: That did not work when I tried it...well I'm not really sure what to say besides thank you. Though I do have a question, why can't I use the "hidden" attribute of html5?

Comment: Ok hold up now. If I go here http://jsfiddle.net/6qDap/970/ it's the exact same thing except different IDs, why won't it work here?

Comment: What I commented earlier. Change onLoad to 'No wrap - in <head>'

Answer (score 1):

The attribute probably needs to be set to a value, try:

```
    document.getElementById('my_div').setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
```

Or alternatively, set the `style` attribute.

```
    document.getElementById('my_div').setAttribute('style', 'visibility: hidden;');
```

Comment: Just tried that, it didn't work either...
Edit: Tried both, don't work. I feel like the issue is with the onclick, it's not actually calling the function.

Comment: Where are you defining this? Sometimes the order can make a difference.

Comment: I'm actually not really using this in anything, I'm just using what's on the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on jsfiddle you should load the javascript on

- No wrap - in - <head>  **or**
- No wrap - in - <body>

[image]

```
function revealPhotos() {
    document.getElementById("div_2008").style.display = "none";
}
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qDap/968/)

Comment: Oh this makes sense as to why mine wasn't working. But why does this make a difference?

Comment: @AnitGandhi if you open the console and check then there will be an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: revealPhotos is not defined` that means the revealPhotos function which you were attaching as click event was not their. always take help of console or developer tools like firebug on firefox.